# find запрос с $and

Tags: mongodb

Это я увидел в видео по mongodb :
(вроде должно быть одинаково , почему так ? это как то связано с одинаковым ключом  - в каждом запросе "И" по два genres  )

```
db.movies.find({ genres:"Drama", genres:"Horror" }).count()
> 23
db.movies.find({ $and:[ {genres:"Drama"}, {genres:"Horror"} ] }).count()
> 17
```

Comment: Можно еще так `db.movies.find({ genres: ["Drama", "Horror"] }).count()`

Comment: А не будет ли в данном случае результаты четко["Drama", "Horror"] то есть исключены например такие : ["Drama", "Horror", "Action"] ?

Comment: Да, будут......

Answer (score 0):

Теперь ясно .Ответ таков что в запросе

```
db.movies.find ( {genres:"Drama", genres:"Horror"} ).count()
>23
```

первый член затирается вторым и получается эквивалентно

```
db.movies.find ( {genres:"Horror"} ).count()
>23
```